# move column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
   a  b   x  y
0  1  2   3 -1
1  2  4   6 -2
2  3  6   9 -3
3  4  8  12 -4
```

How can I move columns b and x such that they are the last 2 columns in the dataframe? I would like to specify b and x by name, but not the other columns.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can rearrange columns directly by specifying their order:

```
df = df[['a', 'y', 'b', 'x']]
```

In the case of larger dataframes where the column titles are dynamic, you can use a list comprehension to select every column not in your target set and then append the target set to the end.

```
>>> df[[c for c in df if c not in ['b', 'x']] 
       + ['b', 'x']]
   a  y  b   x
0  1 -1  2   3
1  2 -2  4   6
2  3 -3  6   9
3  4 -4  8  12
```

To make it more bullet proof, you can ensure that your target columns are indeed in the dataframe:

```
cols_at_end = ['b', 'x']
df = df[[c for c in df if c not in cols_at_end] 
        + [c for c in cols_at_end if c in df]]
```

Comment: can we change the order of a column when there are 10000 columns?

Answer (score 97):

For example, to move column `"name"` to be the first column in df you can use [insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
column_to_move = df.pop("name")

# insert column with insert(location, column_name, column_value)

df.insert(0, "name", column_to_move)
```

similarly, if you want this column to be e.g. third column from the beginning:

```
df.insert(2, "name", column_to_move )
```

Comment: This has to be the best answer, most intuitive and the friendly syntax one would expect. Thanks @montxe

Comment: And if you want to move that column to the end of the dataframe you have you invoke `len(df.columns)` as the positional integer as sadly Pandas haven't implemented the -1 shortcut.

Comment: One-liner: `df.insert(0, 'name', df.pop('name'))`

Answer (score 72):

```
cols = list(df.columns.values) #Make a list of all of the columns in the df
cols.pop(cols.index('b')) #Remove b from list
cols.pop(cols.index('x')) #Remove x from list
df = df[cols+['b','x']] #Create new dataframe with columns in the order you want
```

Answer (score 38):

You can use to way below. It's very simple, but similar to the good answer given by Charlie Haley.

```
df1 = df.pop('b') # remove column b and store it in df1
df2 = df.pop('x') # remove column x and store it in df2
df['b']=df1 # add b series as a 'new' column.
df['x']=df2 # add b series as a 'new' column.
```

Now you have your dataframe with the columns 'b' and 'x' in the end. You can see this video from OSPY : https://youtu.be/RlbO27N3Xg4

Comment: One-liner: `df['b'], df['x'] = df.pop('b'), df.pop('x')`

Answer (score 30):

similar to ROBBAT1's answer above, but hopefully a bit more robust:

```
df.insert(len(df.columns)-1, 'b', df.pop('b'))
df.insert(len(df.columns)-1, 'x', df.pop('x'))
```

Comment: This could be the best answer, at least if you just want to put a single column at the end like I needed it, since it avoids assigning an interim df1 as it is needed in @ROBBAT1's answer, and it also avoids manually rearranging the name list of the columns.

Answer (score 11):

Simple solution:

```py
old_cols = df.columns.values 
new_cols= ['a', 'y', 'b', 'x']
df = df.reindex(columns=new_cols)
```

Comment: found simple and helpful!

Answer (score 10):

This function will reorder your columns without losing data. Any omitted columns remain in the center of the data set:

```
def reorder_columns(columns, first_cols=[], last_cols=[], drop_cols=[]):
    columns = list(set(columns) - set(first_cols))
    columns = list(set(columns) - set(drop_cols))
    columns = list(set(columns) - set(last_cols))
    new_order = first_cols + columns + last_cols
    return new_order
```

Example usage:

```
my_list = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth']
reorder_columns(my_list, first_cols=['fourth', 'third'], last_cols=['second'], drop_cols=['fifth'])

# Output:
['fourth', 'third', 'first', 'sixth', 'second']
```

To assign to your dataframe, use:

```
my_list = df.columns.tolist()
reordered_cols = reorder_columns(my_list, first_cols=['fourth', 'third'], last_cols=['second'], drop_cols=['fifth'])
df = df[reordered_cols]
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative, more generic method;

```
from pandas import DataFrame


def move_columns(df: DataFrame, cols_to_move: list, new_index: int) -> DataFrame:
    """
    This method re-arranges the columns in a dataframe to place the desired columns at the desired index.
    ex Usage: df = move_columns(df, ['Rev'], 2)   
    :param df:
    :param cols_to_move: The names of the columns to move. They must be a list
    :param new_index: The 0-based location to place the columns.
    :return: Return a dataframe with the columns re-arranged
    """
    other = [c for c in df if c not in cols_to_move]
    start = other[0:new_index]
    end = other[new_index:]
    return df[start + cols_to_move + end]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) with [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) or use label-based indexing. In general, it's a good idea to avoid list comprehensions or other explicit loops with NumPy / Pandas objects.

```
cols_to_move = ['b', 'x']
new_cols = np.hstack((df.columns.difference(cols_to_move), cols_to_move))

# OPTION 1: reindex
df = df.reindex(columns=new_cols)

# OPTION 2: direct label-based indexing
df = df[new_cols]

# OPTION 3: loc label-based indexing
df = df.loc[:, new_cols]

print(df)

#    a  y  b   x
# 0  1 -1  2   3
# 1  2 -2  4   6
# 2  3 -3  6   9
# 3  4 -4  8  12
```

Comment: Shortened a bit without using numpy.hstack ```new_cols = list(df.columns.difference(cols_to_move)) + cols_to_move```

Answer (score 4):

You can use movecolumn package in Python to move columns:

```
pip install movecolumn
```

Then you can write your code as:

```
import movecolumn as mc
mc.MoveToLast(df,'b')
mc.MoveToLast(df,'x')
```

Hope that helps.

P.S : The package can be found here. https://pypi.org/project/movecolumn/

Answer (score 1):

One liner per one of the comments:

`df.insert(0, 'name', df.pop('name'))`

By far the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The one line answer I use:

`df.insert(0, "name", df.pop("name"))`

- where `name` is the name of the column you want to move to the start of the DataFrame.
- `0` can move it to any column position, Nth place from the start (left).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this as a one-liner:

```
df.drop(columns=['b', 'x']).assign(b=df['b'], x=df['x'])
```

Comment: This answer could be the "best", even "better" than @Vrun's again, since it needs no mentioning of any df.columns. It works entirely with the column that needs to be shifted.

Comment: Hmm...looks like "modern" python has "fixed" this.  So no longer the best best answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will move any column to the last column :

1. Move any column to the last column of dataframe :

```
df= df[ [ col for col in df.columns if col != 'col_name_to_moved' ] + ['col_name_to_moved']]
```

2. Move any column to the first column of dataframe:

```
df= df[ ['col_name_to_moved'] + [ col for col in df.columns if col != 'col_name_to_moved' ]]
```

where col_name_to_moved is the column that you want to move.

Answer (score 0):

To move a column `x` before another column `y`:

```
col_idx = df.columns.tolist().index('y')
col_mv =  df.pop('x')
df.insert(col_idx, 'x', col_mv)
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Pokémon database as an example, the columns for my data base are

```
['Name', '#', 'Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Total', 'HP', 'Attack', 'Defense', 'Sp. Atk', 'Sp. Def', 'Speed', 'Generation', 'Legendary']
```

Here is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_html('https://gist.github.com/armgilles/194bcff35001e7eb53a2a8b441e8b2c6')[0] 
    cols = df.columns.to_list()
    cos_end= ["Name", "Total", "HP", "Defense"]

    for i, j in enumerate(cos_end, start=(len(cols)-len(cos_end))):
        cols.insert(i, cols.pop(cols.index(j)))
        print(cols)
        
    df = df.reindex(columns=cols)

    print(df)
```

Comment: as here you can see if you did some change at enumerate() u can move columns at any place you wish