# Pandas: change the order of the columns when using crosstab

Tags: python, pandas

Pretty simply, I want to change the order of the columns for Panda's `crosstab`.

Right now, it's in alphabetical order, i.e.: Friday, Monday, Saturday, Sunday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday. I would like it to go in order, i.e.: Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday.

This is for a dataset where I wanted to make a `crosstab` for the days of the week, and the hour of an occurrence.

I'm doing this right now:

```
pd.crosstab(data_2019.HOUR, data_2019.DAY_OF_WEEK)
```

With the output looking like this:

```
DAY_OF_WEEK Friday  Monday  Saturday    Sunday  Thursday    Tuesday Wednesday
HOUR                            
0   204 255 256 260 225 222 192
1   121 111 198 230 116 117 145
2   128 90  217 222 84  111 96
```

Comment: You can explicitly reorder the columns: `pd.crosstab(data_2019.HOUR, data_2019.DAY_OF_WEEK)[['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']]`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321812/move-column-in-pandas-dataframe/35322540#35322540

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list with the days of the week, in the required order. Then you can use `.crosstab` and change the order of the output of running `.crosstab` using

Generate `crosstab`

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
        'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

c = pd.crosstab(...)
```

**One option**

Change order of columns produced by `crosstab`

- this amounts to simply [selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38969308/4057186) **all** the columns, but using a list of weekday names in the order you required, since the `crosstab` output is a just a normal Pandas [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas.crosstab)

```
c = c[days]
```

**Alternatively**

Use [`.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) with `axis='columns'` and specify the list (`days`) to use to change that index (columns) of the `DataFrame`

```
c = c.reindex(days, axis="columns")
```

Answer (score 2):

It is often that one needs to change order of columns and rows, and for that we need to combine approaches outlined the in answer @edesz provided.

For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["one", "two", "three", "three"], "b": ["two", "one", "three", "one"]})

In [3]: pd.crosstab(df["a"], df["b"]) # wrong order
Out[3]:
b      one  three  two
a
one      0      0    1
three    1      1    0
two      1      0    0

In [4]: pd.crosstab(df["a"], df["b"]).reindex(["one", "two", "three"])[["one", "two", "three"]] # correct order
Out[4]:
b      one  two  three
a
one      0    1      0
two      1    0      0
three    1    0      1
```